# Minesweeper C++ - trouble building array from file

Tags: arrays, fstream, minesweeper

For homework I'm making a simple textual minesweeper program. I need to read the array parameters from a text file that will be randomly generated, but to get the program built first I'm using a known sample file. When I read it in however, I just get a jumble of text  - 0xbf followed by some letters, which I think is Unicode. However, I'm able to use infile to assign the first two values to the array dimensions. Any help is appreciated!

```
int main()
{
    //VARIABLES
    int i;
    int j;
    int arrayPos = 0;
    int rowPos;
    int colPos;



        //stream variable declaration
        ifstream infile;

        //open stream files
        infile.open("hw08in.txt");

        infile >> i;
        infile >> j;

        cout << i << " " << j; //test whether the file is being read correctly
        cout << endl;

        int minefield[i][j];
        for(int rowPos=0; rowPos<i; rowPos++)    
    {
        for(int colPos=0; colPos<j; colPos++) 
        {
            infile >> minefield[i][j]; 
        }
    }

        cout << minefield;  



    infile.close();


    return 0;
    }
```

When I run the program, i and j come out to their proper values. However, the array doesn't seem to be being built at all. What is the correct way to build an array from a text file?

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the text file are strings - that is, not in binary format - then the program should read the values into strings then convert the strings into integer values.

Comment: so when for infile, I should read it in as infile.c_str()? If I read them into an array that way, will they automatically become integers?